# .addEventListener('click', classToggle) not working on touch devices

Tags: javascript, button, mobile, addeventlistener

I got a Javascript function that changes between two CSS classes for a button (it changes its background color) when the button is clicked.

```
<button id="div" class="class1" onclick ="change();">ON / OFF</button>

function classToggle() {
    this.classList.toggle('class1');
    this.classList.toggle('class2');
}
document.querySelector('#div').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
```

In know that the 'click' event will not work on touch devices, but i have tried with 'touchastart' and 'touchend' but nothing seems to be working.

I guess the problem is that i cant figure out where to specify the touch friendly addeventlistener??

I can not figure out why, so i hope someone more knowledgeable can help :-)

Best regards

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: Hi Zakaria, i have read a lot of post here on stackoverflow, and other places. But i cant seem to figure out where to state the other eventlistener, and i cant find examples that looks like mine. Could you maybe assist me with this?

Comment: Try to remove the inline `onclick =` and attach the event just from the js using `addEventListener`

Comment: The problem is that onclick = triggers another function from the button

Comment: You should then call the function `change()` also inside the `addEventListener`

Comment: But the eventlistener is what is not working on mobile..... Is it not possible to just ad touchstart to the eventlistener? like this .addEventListener('click touchstart', classToggle) or something like this?

Comment: Could be like `"click touchstart".split(" ").forEach(function(e){
      window.addEventListener(e,change,false);
    });`

Comment: Thank you Zakaria!

Comment: You're welcome, anytime.